# Two slide in divs fired from one button.

Tags: jquery

I need to trigger two slide-in divs with one button. I have played around with http://jsfiddle.net/hoptubtowers1/VmSX4/133/ I want the result like a simple pair of curtains. On the first click, the "red" curtain slides out left and the "green" curtain slides out right. On the second click, the "curtains" will close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just checked it... this script should do the trick.

```
function toggleDivs() {
    var $red = $("#red");
    var $green =$("#green");
       if ($green.position().left*1 == 200) {
            $red.animate({  left: "-400px"  });
            $green.animate({left: "400px"  });
    }
    else {
            $red.animate({  left: "-200px"  });
            $green.animate({left: "200px"  });
    }

}


$("button").bind("click", function() {
    toggleDivs();
});
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect! Thanks a million Anantha.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
var $curtains = $('#red,#green')
$('button').toggle(function(){
  $curtains.animate({
    width:0
  })
},function(){
  $curtains.animate({
    width:'50%'
  })
})
```

And the CSS:

```
#container {
  position:relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 600px;
}
#red {
  width:50%;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  background:red;
}
#green {
  width:50%;
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  background:green;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<button>Click me</button>
<div id="container">
  <div id="red"></div>
  <div id="green"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for looking at this. Much appreciated.